# "Unexpected end of declaration" when dealing with 2D arrays

Tags: java, aide-ide

I have a LibGDX project on my desktop that compiles and runs fine. I imported this project to my phone to use with AIDE-ide and suddenly I have hundreds of errors. I found that any time I use a 2-dimensional array of any sort, the "Unexpected end of declaration" error occurs. This simple example won't compile:

```
package com.mrhart;

public class SampleClass{
    int[][] sampleArray;
}
```

I get 4 compilation errors on the line with the 2D-array declaration all claiming "Unexpected end of declaration". As I said before, this is a working project on my desktop, so I'm not really sure what's going on here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd try cleaning/rebuilding the project. Or maybe it's an AIDE bug... or maybe some dependency is incompatible with Android and is messing up the project build.

Comment: I rebuilt the project so many times already, doesn't help.

Comment: Michael, see my answer. Ihad the same problem and it solved it.

Comment: The actual section is on page 2 http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076614/core-java/object-initialization-in-java.html?page=2  under "Instance variable initializers"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try an initializer block:

```
public class sampleClass{
  {
   int [][] sampleArray;
  }
}
```

as it seems the array declaration is not quite an instance variable declaration. Which is interesting.

ref: [object-initialization-in-java.html](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076614/core-java/object-initialization-in-java.html)